# Toggle selector CSS with multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

**This is what I have:**

A SVG with several lines. These have types as CSS classes.
For example: ***.pen1 .pen2 .pen3 .pen4. and .special***

Every line has one of the first four and can have .spcial!
There are also some .special only lines.

It's possible do activate and deactivate each of these classes with buttons.

**My problem is:**

*(Line A has .pen1, Line B has .pen1 .special, Line C has .pen2, Line D has .pen2 .special)*

Following procedure:

- 1) I click the button for .pen1: A & B disappear
- 2) I click the button for .special: D disapperas and B appears
- 3) I click the button for .pen1: A appears & B disappear

But I need both to disappear in 2) and after that both should reappear in 3).

My current solution is, If I press the button for .pen1 i set a flag that it was pressed and test this flag when I press .special --> This works, but only if only one class has its own and the .special class

**This is my code right now:**

for special toggling:

```
if (this._pen1|| this._pen2|| this.pen3|| this.pen4 ){
      if (this.special) {
        if (this.pen1) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen1).hide(0);
        }
        if (this.pen2) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen2).hide(0);
        }
        if (this.pen3) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen3).hide(0);
        }
        if (this.pen4) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen4).hide(0);
        }
      } else {
        if (this.pen1) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen1).show(0);
        }
        if (this.pen2) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen2).show(0);
        }
        if (this.pen3) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen3).show(0);
        }
        if (this.pen4) {
          [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.pen4).show(0);
        }
      }
    } else {
      [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.special).toggle(0);
    }
    this.special= !this.special;
```

for pen1-4 toggling:

```
    if (this.special) {
      [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.pen1).not('.' + _PENSTYLES.special).toggle(0);
    } else {
      [...].find('svg .' + _PENSTYLES.pen1).toggle(0);
    }
    this.pen1= !this.pen1;
```

I hope someone can help me how I do it for my problem with multiple lines.
Because right now they pen2 overrides pen1 and show/hides everything which was excluded in the others.

Comment: I'm sorrry I am having problems understanding the use cases to your question, can you help list out each use case you are trying to cover?

Comment: @B.Cratty I don't know exactly what you mean with use cases? I need this to disable & enable different lines (paths) in a SVG

Comment: A use case is another way of saying a scenario for example in your situation a use case would be "If i click any button with class `Pen1`, then any button with class `Pen2` should dissappear" or something like "When I click a button with a `selected` class then all buttons will disappear"

Comment: I did provide this: Look for **Following procedure:** in my post

Comment: This is hyper repetitive, and should be DRYed up significantly. It would be very helpful to see the rest of the code.

Comment: @Ted this is all the code (the rest has nothing to do with my problem). --> there is an action system around for button handling.

Comment: @Ted The html is just empty page with the buttons and the svg. Sorry, I can't post the svg or more code, cause It's company property... The SVG has several pathes and these all have class names. `<path class="pen1" ....> <path class=pen1 special">` and so on. All these classes hava a stroke-width and color... I just hope for a solution to get the togging done without my hyper repetition and a working one, which doesn't enable already disabled classes (when the button for it is still pressed) and vice versa

Comment: @breezertwo Let me see if I can make a quick demo for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplification of what I think you're looking for to get you started. Run the snippet to see it work.

```js
var hidden = [];

function toggle(classname) {
  if (hidden.indexOf(classname) > -1) {
    hidden.splice(hidden.indexOf(classname), 1);
    getElements(classname).forEach(function(ele) {
      ele.classList.remove("hidden");
    });
  } else {
    hidden.push(classname);
  }
  hidden.forEach(function(hide) {
    getElements(hide).forEach(function(ele) {
      ele.classList.add("hidden")
    });
  })
}

function getElements(classname) {
  return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(classname));
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
}

.root>div {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
}
button{
 width: 70px;
}

svg line {
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.special {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 5;
}

.pen1 {
  stroke: blue;
}

.pen2 {
  stroke: green;
}

.pen3 {
  stroke: goldenrod;
}

.pen4 {
  stroke: DarkOrchid;
}

text {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div>
    <button onclick="toggle('pen1')">.pen1</button>
    <button onclick="toggle('pen2')">.pen2</button>
    <button onclick="toggle('pen3')">.pen3</button>
    <button onclick="toggle('pen4')">.pen4</button>
    <button onclick="toggle('special')">.special</button>
  </div>

  <svg width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <rect width="400" height="200" fill="#efefef" />
  <line class="pen1" y1="20" y2="20" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen2" y1="40" y2="40" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen3" y1="60" y2="60" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen4" y1="80" y2="80" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen1 special" y1="100" y2="100" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen2 special" y1="120" y2="120" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen3 special" y1="140" y2="140" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="pen4 special" y1="160" y2="160" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <line class="special" y1="180" y2="180" x1="0" x2="300" />
  <text x="310" y="20" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen1</text>
  <text x="310" y="40" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen2</text>
  <text x="310" y="60" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen3</text>
  <text x="310" y="80" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen4</text>
  <text x="310" y="100" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen1 .special</text>
  <text x="310" y="120" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen2 .special</text>
  <text x="310" y="140" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen3 .special</text>
  <text x="310" y="160" alignment-baseline="middle">.pen4 .special</text>
  <text x="310" y="180" alignment-baseline="middle">.special</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver. Thanks a lot. I see what i did wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a hint. You can always add another , Same named , class for elements that you want to toggle. .pen1 and .pen2 can both have class "hidden" with some attributes in it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: unfortunately I can't add classes (I should have mentioned that). The SVG arrives from a server and these are the classes i can work with (enabling & disabling them)

Comment: You can use attribute=value maybe. That is the only thing that comes to mind now .https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp